# Proguard and error

Tags: java, android, proguard

I use this proguard file:

```
 -dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
 -dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers

 !code/simplification/arithmetic,!code/simplification/cast,!field/*,!class/merging/*
 -optimizationpasses 10
 -allowaccessmodification
 -mergeinterfacesaggressively
 -overloadaggressively

 -assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
*;
 }

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgent
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment
-keep public class * extends com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockListFragment
-keep public class * extends com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment
-keep public class * extends com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Fragment
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
-keep public class org.jsoup.** {
public *;
}

-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
 public <init>(android.content.Context);
 public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
 public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
 public void set*(...);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
 public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
 public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
 public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
 public static **[] values();
 public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
 public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
 public static <fields>;
}

-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep class com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }
-keep interface com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }

-keep class com.google.ads.** {*;}
-keep class com.google.ads.internal.** {*;}
-keep class com.google.ads.mediation.** {*;}
-keep class com.google.ads.mediation.adfonic.** {*;}
-keep class com.google.ads.mediation.admob.** {*;}
-keep class com.google.ads.mediation.adfonic.util.** {*;}
-keep class com.google.ads.mediation.customevent.** {*;}
-keep class com.google.ads.searchads.** {*;}
-keep class com.google.ads.util.** {*;}

-dontwarn android.support.**
-dontwarn com.google.ads.**
```

But after some update on the code, I have the following errors:

```
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw$zza: can't find superclass or interface org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase
Warning:com.google.android.gms.analytics.internal.zzam: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.NameValuePair
Warning:com.google.android.gms.analytics.internal.zzam: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils
Warning:com.google.android.gms.analytics.internal.zzam: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.NameValuePair
Warning:com.google.android.gms.analytics.internal.zzj: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.NameValuePair
Warning:com.google.android.gms.analytics.internal.zzj: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils
Warning:com.google.android.gms.analytics.internal.zzj: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.NameValuePair
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzac: can't find referenced class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.StatusLine
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.conn.ClientConnectionManager
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.StatusLine
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.conn.ClientConnectionManager
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.Header
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.StatusLine
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.cookie.DateUtils
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.Header
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.StatusLine
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.Header
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpDelete
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpHead
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpOptions
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPut
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpTrace
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.entity.ByteArrayEntity
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced method 'void addHeader(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)' in program class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw$zza
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpDelete
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpHead
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpOptions
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPut
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpTrace
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.entity.ByteArrayEntity
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw$zza: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw$zza: can't find referenced method 'void setURI(java.net.URI)' in program class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw$zza
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw$zza: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.cookie.DateParseException
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.cookie.DateUtils
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzy: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzz: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.ProtocolVersion
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzz: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.entity.BasicHttpEntity
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzz: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzz: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzz: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.message.BasicStatusLine
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzz: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.ProtocolVersion
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzz: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.entity.BasicHttpEntity
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzz: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzz: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzz: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.message.BasicStatusLine
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzz: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzz: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
Warning:com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzby: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient
Warning:com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzcx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.Header
Warning:com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzcx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
Warning:com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzcx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntityEnclosingRequest
Warning:com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzcx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpHost
Warning:com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzcx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning:com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzcx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.StatusLine
Warning:com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzcx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
Warning:com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzcx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
Warning:com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzcx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest
Warning:com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzcx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpHost
Warning:com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzcx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest
Warning:com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzcx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
Warning:com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzcx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntityEnclosingRequest
Warning:com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzcx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning:com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzcx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.StatusLine
Warning:com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzcx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
Warning:com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzcx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntityEnclosingRequest
```

I tried with:

```
-keep class org.apache.http.**
-keep interface org.apache.http.**
-dontwarn org.apache.**
```

But still doesn't works, what's wrong? I really don't understand what can I do.
PS do you have any suggestions in order to optimize my file?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are these warnings from ProGuard itself or from your program when it runs?

Comment: These warning are from Android Studio when I try to make a Signed APK as I always do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't generate APK after adding Google Analytics, but working fine in debug mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32409990/cant-generate-apk-after-adding-google-analytics-but-working-fine-in-debug-mode)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I had the same problem.

I found the answer here and it worked for me: [How to add Apache HTTP API (legacy) as compile-time dependency to build.grade?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30856785/how-to-add-apache-http-api-legacy-as-compile-time-dependency-to-build-grade)

**In your top level build.gradle file add:**

```
buildscript {
    ...
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
    }
}
...
```

**In your app-specific build.gradle file add:**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    ...
}
```

Hope it works for you! it works now with ProGuard on. I had the exact same problem as you.

Comment: It does not work with `libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar`.

Answer (score 17):

It looks like the warning comes from the google library, have you tried something like that:

```
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-keep class com.google.android.gms.**
```

I would also try without the `dontwarn` cause I would assume you want to be warned if there is something to be warned about!

Comment: Would this be a similar problem? https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=3001

Comment: Yes, I was reading, but with:
```
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-dontwarn android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-dontwarn com.android.volley.toolbox.**

still doesn't works.

Comment: Must something else then... Sorry this didn't help.

Answer (score 9):

In Eclipse find org.apache.http.legacy.jar in ..sdk/platforms/android-23/optional.

Import it like external jar, check order/export and in proguard type:

```
-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class org.apache.http.** {*;}
-dontwarn org.apache.**

-keep class android.net.http.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class android.net.http.** {*;}
-dontwarn android.net.**
```

Answer (score 1):

Add following lines in your proguard file.

```
-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.apache.**
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.**
```