# ProGuard build fail "Unresolved references"

Tags: android, proguard, android-build, android-proguard

I've been working on the newest version of my app and it tests just fine, but when I do a release ProGuard build, I get many errors, mostly about not being able to find `org.apache.http.*`, which I do not use in my project. I have searched my entire project for that text and cannot find it. I have added some dependencies but none which I *think* would use HTTP.

How do I figure out *why* ProGuard is complaining and address it properly? It says I can run "with --stacktrace option", but I can't figure out how to do that.

I appreciate any help, as I find ProGuard often confusing.

Build output:

```
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw$zza: can't find superclass or interface org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase
Warning: com.google.android.gms.analytics.internal.zzam: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.NameValuePair
Warning: com.google.android.gms.analytics.internal.zzam: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils
Warning: com.google.android.gms.analytics.internal.zzam: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils
Warning: com.google.android.gms.analytics.internal.zzam: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.NameValuePair
Warning: com.google.android.gms.analytics.internal.zzam: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.NameValuePair
Warning: com.google.android.gms.analytics.internal.zzj: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.NameValuePair
Warning: com.google.android.gms.analytics.internal.zzj: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils
Warning: com.google.android.gms.analytics.internal.zzj: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils
Warning: com.google.android.gms.analytics.internal.zzj: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.NameValuePair
Warning: com.google.android.gms.analytics.internal.zzj: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.NameValuePair
Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced method 'void setLatestEventInfo(android.content.Context,java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence,android.app.PendingIntent)' in library class android.app.Notification
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzac: can't find referenced class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzac: can't find referenced class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqj: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqj: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqj: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.StatusLine
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqj: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqj: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqj: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.conn.ClientConnectionManager
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqj: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqj: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqj: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqj: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqj: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqj: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqj: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqj: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqj: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.StatusLine
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqj: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqj: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqj: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.conn.ClientConnectionManager
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqj: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqj: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqj: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqj: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqj: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.Header
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.Header
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.StatusLine
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.cookie.DateUtils
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.cookie.DateUtils
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.Header
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.Header
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.StatusLine
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.StatusLine
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.StatusLine
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.Header
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzt: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.Header
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpDelete
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpHead
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpOptions
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPut
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpTrace
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.entity.ByteArrayEntity
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced method 'void addHeader(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)' in program class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw$zza
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpDelete
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpHead
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpOptions
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPut
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPut
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpTrace
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.entity.ByteArrayEntity
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw$zza: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw$zza: can't find referenced method 'void setURI(java.net.URI)' in program class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw$zza
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw$zza: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.cookie.DateParseException
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.cookie.DateUtils
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.cookie.DateUtils
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzy: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzy: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzz: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.ProtocolVersion
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzz: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.entity.BasicHttpEntity
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzz: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzz: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzz: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.message.BasicStatusLine
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzz: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.ProtocolVersion
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzz: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.entity.BasicHttpEntity
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzz: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.entity.BasicHttpEntity
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzz: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.entity.BasicHttpEntity
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzz: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.entity.BasicHttpEntity
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzz: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.entity.BasicHttpEntity
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzz: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzz: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzz: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzz: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzz: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.message.BasicStatusLine
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzz: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzz: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzz: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
Warning: com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzby: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient
Warning: com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzby: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient
Warning: com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzcx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.Header
Warning: com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzcx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
Warning: com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzcx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntityEnclosingRequest
Warning: com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzcx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpHost
Warning: com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzcx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning: com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzcx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.StatusLine
Warning: com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzcx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
Warning: com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzcx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
Warning: com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzcx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest
Warning: com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzcx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpHost
Warning: com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzcx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpHost
Warning: com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzcx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest
Warning: com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzcx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
Warning: com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzcx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
Warning: com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzcx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntityEnclosingRequest
Warning: com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzcx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntityEnclosingRequest
Warning: com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzcx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntityEnclosingRequest
Warning: com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzcx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntityEnclosingRequest
Warning: com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzcx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning: com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzcx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning: com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzcx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.StatusLine
Warning: com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzcx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
Warning: com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzcx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
Warning: com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzcx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
Warning: com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzcx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntityEnclosingRequest
Warning: com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzcx: can't find referenced class org.apache.http.HttpEntityEnclosingRequest
Warning: there were 148 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
         If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
Warning: there were 2 unresolved references to program class members.
         Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
         You may need to recompile the code.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedprogramclassmember)
Warning: there were 1 unresolved references to library class members.
         You probably need to update the library versions.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedlibraryclassmember)
:GradeTrackerPro:proguardRelease FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':MyApp:proguardRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

From my Gradle file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')


        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled true
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                        'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }


    // to ignore warnings and strings not converted to all languages
    android {
        lintOptions {
            checkReleaseBuilds false
            // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
            // but continue the build even when errors are found:
            abortOnError false
        }
    }
```

My `proguard-rules.pro` file:

```
-keep class !android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder, !android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.SubMenuBuilder, android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.opencsv.bean.**

-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable  # these last two lines keep info for debugging

# added these because proguard was complaining. Not sure where they could be referenced!



# For Flurry
-keep class com.flurry.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.flurry.**
-keepattributes *Annotation*, EnclosingMethod
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int) ;
}
# Google Play Services library
-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
protected Object[][] getContents() ;
}
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
public static final *** NULL;
}
-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
@com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}
-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
public static final ** CREATOR;
}
```

Comment: Please take a look at [issue #3001: PlayServices problems with proguard](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=3001)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proguard and error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32596858/proguard-and-error)

Comment: this is a really simple issue to solve. see my answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/34483791/4538504

Answer (score 18):

I never face this issue before updating buildTool to 23.0. The only workaround that i could see with this newer version of build tools for my App was, you need to add this to your Progaurd.txt file.

```
-dontwarn android.support.v4.**
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.* { public *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
```

If you are using Apache's Http in your project, you need to include the following lines too:

```
-keepnames class org.apache.** {*;}
-keep public class org.apache.** {*;}    
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
-dontwarn org.apache.http.annotation.ThreadSafe
-dontwarn org.apache.http.annotation.Immutable
-dontwarn org.apache.http.annotation.NotThreadSafe
```

Let me know if this helps to resolve your issue too.

Comment: I had the same problem after 23.0 upgrade and -dontwarn com.google.android.gms.** fixed it. I didn't need the others. Thank you

Comment: @Shine Actually you need to add those other lines only if were still using the old Apache Http library for Network calls. I have further clarified in the answer. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Why do you need `public` for **com.google.android.gms**?

Comment: I'm still having problem with `Warning:twitter4j.TwitterAPIMonitor` and `Warning:com.squareup.picasso` how can I solve it ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add to your build.gradle file the following if your app uses the old apache HttpClient :

useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

as explained here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yYU4DHLwoRk

Comment: I already put `org.apache.http.legacy` in my `build.gradle` but I still have the errors