# proguard issue in Gradle

Tags: android, android-proguard

I am trying build my APP I am getting the following error: All this time App used to generate the build properly.

After I upgraded my compileSdkVersion and build to 23, GMS to 8.1, AsyncHttpclient to 1.4.9. I am getting the following error.

Not sure what to do:

```
  Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzac: can't find referenced class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient
    Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw: can't find referenced method 'void addHeader(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)' in program class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw$zza
    Warning:com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw$zza: can't find referenced method 'void setURI(java.net.URI)' in program class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzw$zza
    Warning:there were 2 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
             You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
             If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
             the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
             (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
    Warning:there were 2 unresolved references to program class members.
             Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
             You may need to recompile the code.
             (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedprogramclassmember)
    :app:proguardRelease FAILED
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:proguardRelease'.
    > java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

What could be wrong here?

Comment: You may need to see your proguard and add any new commands for AsyncHttpclient library.

Comment: did you add necessary dontwarn command in proguard?

Comment: @Shvet: Not sure what are the don't warn part? As I told before it was working.. This is coming after the update. How do I know what should I add?

Comment: @user5287166 did you make `minifyEnabled false` to true? when you updated gradle?

Comment: Isn't it similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32596858/proguard-and-error)?

Comment: @Dhaval I changed minifyEnabled false to true. any suggestion?

Comment: @BinqiangSun it means you are enabling proguard, you have to check all necessary class name into dontwarn and keep inside proguard.

Answer (score 0):

If you havent added command in progruard yet then add.

```
-keep class com.google.android.gms.maps.** { *; }
-keep interface com.google.android.gms.maps.** { *; }
```

If you are using map you should check developer site. There is proguard in it already.

For map you may need to add below code. if you havent added.

```
# The Maps API uses custom Parcelables.
# Use this rule (which is slightly broader than the standard recommended one)
# to avoid obfuscating them.
-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static *** CREATOR;
}

# The Maps API uses serialization.
-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}

-dontwarn com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint
-dontwarn com.google.android.maps.MapActivity
-dontwarn com.google.android.maps.MapView
-dontwarn com.google.android.maps.MapController
-dontwarn com.google.android.maps.Overlay
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.maps.model.*
```